# run .jar file with properties config file

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd, configuration-files

I have a `jar` file with `properties` configuration file.

when I run it in `Netbeans` everything works as it should.

but when I run it in a `cmd` - the properties file is not found.

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you're loading your properties file.
Consider to load your properties with the help of:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/log4j.properties");
```

and then use Properties.load(in)

This should handle the situation when the properties file physically resides in the jar
Good Luck!

Comment: thanks, but i got an error about `getclass()` function:
non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: What is your error, the getClass() will work if you're not in the static method.

Comment: If you're inside main method (which is static), and your class is named MyClass (for example), try this way: MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...)

Comment: I think you better post the whole Exception stack trace here. This will help the community to figure out the issue.

Comment: the `InputStream` in received a null.


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
 at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
 at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
 at myclass.myclass.main(myclass.java:31)

Comment: This means that you simply don't have such a properties file in your classpath. Do you run your binaries in jar or you're using *.class files directly? If you deal with jar, open it (a usual winzip/winrar will do the job) and ensure that you do have a properties file. If you don't use jar, figure out where does your property file reside and add this directory to the classpath (use java -cp option).

Answer (score 1):

When you package the properties inside the jar file, you have to use the class loader to locate the file since it is no longer *visible* as a file.

If the properties file is insider the jar file at the **root** of the jar file then the answer given above is what you would use:

```
 Properties p = new Properties();
 InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properities");
 if( is != null )
 {
    p.load(is);
 }
```

that should return an InputStream that you can pass to the Properities class to load.  If that call returns a NULL then you need to see where the property file is *relative to the root of the jar file*.